# How to add base url dynamically in single-spa-router in react app

Tags: html, reactjs, environment-variables, single-spa

We are using Single Spa Micro Front end for our react app to load the pages from multiple front ends. I would like to load a base URL from an env variable in `microfrontend-layout.html`

Our **microfrontend-layout.html** looks like this.

```
<single-spa-router base="@basePath"> 
  <main style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <route default>
      <h1>404 route not defined</h1>
    </route>

    <route path="/login">
          <application  name="@login"></application>
    </route>

    <route path="/dashboard">
          <application  name="@dashboard"></application>
    </route>
</main>
</single-spa-router>
```

And our **index.ejs** import looks like this.

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
            
            "@root-config": "HTTP://someurl",
            "@login": "someurl",
            "@dasboard": "someurl",
            "@basePath": ''
        }
    }
    </script>
    <% } %>
```

Now, I want to add a `base` URL dynamically. So I tried to add that in an `imports` of `index.ejs` and read it in the HTML file which is not working.

My requirement is reading a value from an environment .env file and assigning that to the `base` attribute in **microfrontend-layout.html**. Since I cannot read the environment variable in the HTML file, I thought of reading that from the **index.ejs** file.

Please guide me on the right way to achieve this.

Comment: You probably need to configure a proxy in your React app. using that you can for example forward any http route that starts with "/api/**" to another address (ex. localhost:5252/api/**)

Comment: You can implement a proxy in react by following this answer [http proxy middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839508/8931133)