Cross-Origin Request Blocked. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404
I am trying to run a spring boot application with a react front-end following a video. I have my back-end on http://localhost:8080/api/v1/movies/ and it works just fine when I try to access it. When trying to access it using react on http://localhost:3000/. I keep getting CORS error.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://9c96-103-106-239-104.ap.ngrok.io/api/v1/movies. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://9c96-103-106-239-104.ap.ngrok.io/api/v1/movies. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
My controller on spring boot is as follows:
package dev.harshaNeelathi.movies_app;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movieService.allMovies(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{imdbId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> getSingleMovie(@PathVariable String imdbId){
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>>(movieService.singleMovie(imdbId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

my front-end :
axios config file:
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://9c96-103-106-239-104.ap.ngrok.io/",
  headers: {
    "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "true",
  },
});

app.jsx:
import "./App.css";
import api from "./api/axiosConfig";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState();

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get("/api/v1/movies");
      console.log(response.data);

      setMovies(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;

I have tried adding the following annotation to my controller, but it did not work and I am still getting the error:
@CrossOrigin(origins= {"*"}, maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false" )
i tried changing the url in axios congif file to my api url but still doesn't work.
I have tried to install the CORS block extention in chrome, but it still doesn't work.
i have tried to add  --d
isable-web-security and --user-data-dir to my chrome shortcut, but it still doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me on this issue. I have been trying all sorts of things from the web but none seem to work for me.

Do you use Spring-Security?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697883/can-you-completely-disable-cors-support-in-spring

dont allow cors from backend. try to use proxy config in front end. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766424/proxy-config-in-react

@Nico-S, No I haven't used spring security, the api itself is very simple and barebones, I am just trying to fetch data from front-end but for the life of me can't figure out how to get rid of the cors error

@GolamMazid Sajib
I have tried adding proxy in the package.json file  as  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/", but its still giving me the cors error

Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697883/can-you-completely-disable-cors-support-in-spring

yes, i have tried that as well, doesn't seem to work. I had cors issue with another project as well using express, but I couldn't solve it there as well
